# How to make Base form controls not visible in child form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a main windows form and another form that inherits from it.

The second form needs to access the controls (Buttons, PictureBox, etc.) of the main form.
Because it inherits from the main form, the default appearance of the child form is identical to the default appearance of the main form.

How can I overcome this and access the main form's controls at the same time?

I don't want to be forced to change my design again!

**Question is solved, Thnx for answers...**

Comment: Um, not quite clear. You have `Form1` that opens `Form2`, which is defined as `Form2 : Form1`? And now you want the default appearance of `Form2` to be different than the default appearance of `Form1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I inherit the other form from the main form, the appearance of the inhereited one becomes exactly like main form.
>
> How can I overcome this and access the main form's controls at the same time.

Well, simply don't inherit it. How and why did you inherit it? And what do you want to access?

If on `Form2` you have the following code:

```
private Form1 _form1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this._form1 = form1;
}

public void DoSomethingWithForm1()
{
    this._form1.SomeControl.DoSomething();
}
```

Then in `DoSomethingWithForm1` you can call methods and access controls on the other form. This is however not a clever design, you'd rather work with Data Transfer Objects or a kind of FormRepository that contains all your forms and passes data between them, so your forms won't have to know about each other.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way!
But couldnt you pass
"this"
through in the constructor this then allows you to then access the public functions you have inside your form

Answer (score 0):

Generate all controls on mainform as public fields and access it.

Comment: Hi.I know that. What I ask How not to see the controls in derived form and access the controls at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can change access type from 'private' to 'protected'.
It can be done both in code and using GUI Designed.
In GUI Designer this property called 'Modifiers'

Comment: Hey.I've made it, but I still see the control in the derived form.

Comment: May be I misunderstood you but if you inherited from some BaseForm than you received all content of that BaseForm on the InheritedForm. If you don't want this just don't do this. Use @CodeCaster approach.

And please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like following, which decide whether or not to show base control.

```
public partial class baseForm : Form
    {
        bool canShowControls;

        public baseForm(bool canShowBaseControls)
            : this()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            canShowControls = canShowBaseControls;
        }
        public baseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            HideControls();
        }

        void HideControls()
        {
            this.button1.Visible = canShowBaseControls;
            this.txtBox.Text = canShowBaseControls;
        }
    }


public partial class childForm : baseForm
    {
        public childForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public childForm(bool canShowBaseControl = true)
            : base(canShowBaseControl)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Oo I get it. I don't need to inherit the form that I want to use its controls.

Comment: OK, now post that as an edit or comment to your OP so people stop trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to change the default property values from a parent form's controls in a child form at design time. You can add code to Form_Load to change the values in the child.

To be clear: although the child form you opened inherits from its opener, they are *not* the same instance. You will need to pass the main form instance as a parameter to the child form's constructor.

```
PopupForm myPopupForm = new PopupForm(this);


// PopupForm.cs
public class PopupForm : MainForm {
    MainForm _opener;

    public PopupForm(MainForm opener) {
        _opener = opener;
    }
}
```